# Livekit - Angular implementation

Tags: angular, webrtc, livekit

I'm currently trying to implement a Livekit in my Angular (13) app.

I installed the "livekit-client": "^1.14.1", and also added the "@types/webrtc": "^0.0.39" to the devDependencies and the tsConfig.

I'm currently getting this error when I ngServe:

```
Error: node_modules/livekit-client/dist/src/e2ee/utils.d.ts:4:100 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RTCEncodedVideoFrame'.

4 export declare function isVideoFrame(frame: RTCEncodedAudioFrame | RTCEncodedVideoFrame): frame is RTCEncodedVideoFrame;
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely related to your TypeScript version.
Support for `RTCEncodedAudioFrame` has only been added in 4.7